# Plots showing \begin{figure} and \caption{"XXX"} when knitting to pdf

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

When I knit to a pdf in markdown, I am having the raw LaTex commands show in the pdf.  Any idea what's going on?  I've tried changing the captions and alignment, but all the text after this figure in the file is centered.

[image: Knitted pdf]

I've tried playing with the fig.align and fig.cap arguments, as well as checking that my code blocks are self-contained.  Nothing so far has resolved by problem

```
coef_data <- tidy(freq_long_model)
coef_data <- coef_data[-c(1,18:21),]

coef_data$conf.low <- coef_data$estimate - (1.96*coef_data$std.error)
coef_data$conf.high <- coef_data$estimate + (1.96*coef_data$std.error)

coef_data$term <- c("CCI = 1", "CCI = 2", "CCI = 3", "CCI = 4", "CCI = 6", "CESDtot", "Age", "Female", "Years of Ed.", "APOE4+", "Visit #", "CCI = 1 * Visit", "CCI = 2 * Visit", "CCI = 3 * Visit", "CCI = 4 * Visit", "CCI = 6 * Visit")

ggplot(coef_data, aes(x = term, y = estimate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0.2) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Predictor", y = "Estimate") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don’t use images of code as it cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Questions should be reproducible. This makes it easy for other who may want to help, copy the relevant code and data easily. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably sure the problem is caused by the `%` sign in the caption, and [this problem](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2302) has already been fixed in the latest version of **knitr**, so please [try to update your R packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/):

```r
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
# or if you don't want to update all packages, you can just
# install.packages('knitr')
```